# Possible to connect multiple InfiniBand switches?

Tags: infiniband

Is it possible to connect multiple InfiniBand switches? If so, how can this be done? I've attempted to connect the switches directly via a cable, but that is not working, so I assume that I will need to configure the switches via the console, if this is even possible.

Comment: Could you add more details of your setup by editing your question? What kind of switches do you have, what kind of cabling, what sort of hosts and HCAs, how do you check if the fabric is continuous?

Comment: "I've attempted to connect the switches directly via a cable, but that is not working" - what does this mean? How do you check that "is is working" vs "it is not working"?

Comment: The switches are Voltaire 4036s. Not working as in, there is no connection between the servers at each end.